# Twilio Server websocket default string not working [twilio]

Tags: twilio

I can not connect WebSocket connection
This my SIP credential and try to connect in web browser AND following port are my attempt. Still not getting success.

wss://welcome.sip.twilio.com:5060

wss://welcome.sip.twilio.com:5061

wss://welcome.sip.twilio.com:5063

wss://welcome.sip.twilio.com:443

Comment: Not sure what you're trying here. The Twilio web sockets are used by our various SDKs but aren't publicly documented. Are you using one of the Twilio SDKs?

Comment: no, I am trying connect  using SIPjs

Comment: As in my answer, that is not what they are for. Can I ask what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to use Webrtc  with Twilio provider.

Comment: Have you tried using [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio web sockets are used by our various SDKs but aren't publicly documented as they aren't for public use. They don't use your SIP credentials to connect, but are used for real time data in SDKs like [Twilio Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat).